# "Cry foul" - is foul a noun?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Is the the word "foul" in the saying "cry foul" a noun, an adjective or an adverb?
I had a disagreement with my teacher, where I think it's a noun.

As in screaming "Foul!", saying that the action is a foul. Now that I think of it, screaming "Foul!" could also mean that the action was foul.

So is it possible to determine which is it? Or how is it used in say football?

I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32476/discussion-on-question-by-varis-cry-foul-is-foul-a-noun).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As commented above, there is no real meaning in trying to determine what foul's "part of speech (POS)" is.

According to Urban Dictionary (which is deemed not very reliable though), "[cry foul](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cry+foul)" came from a baseball term "foul ball".

> Someone who strongly disagrees with another person's fair
>   opinion/criticism. It came from a baseball term, "foul ball".

[Foul](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/foul) has a noun usage as follows:

> (In sport) an unfair or invalid stroke or piece of play, especially
>   one involving interference with an opponent:

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Considering the fact that articles are omitted in idioms such as "[cry wolf](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cry-wolf?q=cry+a+wolf)", "cry murder", etc. and "foul" has a noun usage, it would be more appropriate to determine it is a "noun".

Comment: It's may also be short for *"cry foul play"*, which was around in the 19th century (whereas *"cry foul ball"* wasn't).

Comment: @PeterShor I am not sure what "play" in the 19th century meant. A game or theater? The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cry+foul+play%2C+cry+foul&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccry%20foul%20play%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccry%20foul%3B%2Cc0) shows cry foul existed in the 19th century though.

Comment: It meant both. But *"cry foul play"* seems to have been used for cheating in gambling, for not playing fair in fights, and for metaphorical extensions to life in general.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, I think that's what it meant. [Foul](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=foul&searchmode=none) seems to have been around for a very long time from Old English.

Comment: For crying (foul) out loud. "Foul" is a word.  Its part of speech is irrelevant.  The properly punctuated expression is "Cry 'Foul!'", and the content of the inner quotes has no effect on the syntax of the overall sentence.  It could as well be "Cry 'Glibnix!'", and the syntax would remain unchanged.

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid I disagree with the other answers listed here. While it is true that when one were to "cry, 'foul'", in the act of doing so the phrase could conceivably be argued grammatically to be an interjection, that notwithstanding in the context of the original question it refers to the *concept* of one crying, "Foul play!" (which, AFAIK, is the original context in which the phrase was introduced into common vernacular). Strangely, I was unable to corroborate the etymological origins of the phrase in a brief search, but Google's Ngram Viewer suggests the phrase entered use circa 1820, 8 years prior to the introduction of the "foul ball" in baseball. "Foul play", on the other hand, has been used since at least 1636.

All of that aside, and regardless of the (debatable) interjectory nature of one crying, "Foul play!" the word "foul" is still an adjective describing the nature of the observed shenanigans. Moreover, I'd argue that "Foul play!" is not strictly an interjection (such as "Yikes!" or "Wow!") regardless of the exclamation point at the end of the sentence. An interjection conveys emotion and nothing else, whereas the statement in question conveys, "[I believe] foul play [is taking place]!" and the extraneous exposition is simply implicit.

**TL;DR: the word "foul" in the context of the original statement is an adjective, defining the nature of the play being observed. The accepted answer above, suggesting that it is a noun, is certainly incorrect by any measure.**

Comment: Could it be that "Foul play" shortened into "a foul" over time and then is used as "cry [a] wolf" -> "cry [a] foul", with "wolf" being a noun?

Comment: Many of the 19th century hits for *"cry foul"* in Google Ngram are actually *"cry foul play*". [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cry+foul%2Ccry+foul+play&year_start=1800&year_end=1960&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccry%20foul%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccry%20foul%20play%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I like this answer.  It seems that as the phrase as been shortened with time, "foul" should still be considered an adjective,  though perhaps now in the substantive form (i.e., an adjective that acts as a noun, like Americans or whites).  This might be splitting hairs, but then, would you call fishing a noun or a verb? (Or be precise and call it a gerund?)

Comment: As you can see in the above comments, I myself started to think it was an adjective first. But I changed my mind as there is a noun usage of the word "foul". I think it is just "tomayto-tomahto" issue. There could be no incorrect answer. If you look at all those 4 answers posted, all of them have a valid point including yours (+1).

Comment: *Foul* is a noun in the [Laws of the Game](http://www.fifa.com/mm/Document/FootballDevelopment/Refereeing/02/36/01/11/LawsofthegamewebEN_Neutral.pdf) of association football, especially Law 12.  So crying "Foul!" can be using an adjective or noun (or perhaps as an imperative verb, inciting cheating),

Comment: @Henry: Perhaps, but the phrase in question (and its associated grammar) predates that text by centuries.

Comment: @user2845306 '... would you call _fishing_ a noun or a verb? Or be precise and call it a gerund?' I'd advise you to look at some of the articles here dealing with the different usages of _ing_-forms (and how various grammarians such as Quirk and Aarts categorise and name them).

Comment: How is that germane to the discussion? We aren't talking about gerunds.

Answer (score 7):

The answers given do not explicitly state that (most don't even acknowledge that), in spite of the obvious literal origin of the expression, **cry foul** is now a verbo-nominal idiom in its own right.

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cry-foul) gives

> Definition of cry foul in English:
>
> Protest strongly about a real or imagined wrong or injustice:
>   *deprived of the crushing victory it was confidently expecting, the party cried foul*

The direct speech interpretation

> The fans all cried "Foul!"

needs the quotation marks to disambiguate (although in other cases, there is an acceptance of intermediate structures, omitting quotation marks where they would once have been regarded as mandatory. 'He wished them Merry Christmas.') This is therefore not indicated in OP; '... the **saying** "cry foul" ' confirms this. [bolding mine]

Although the fact that 'cry foul' is a verbo-nominal structure, analysing it as [V + N] is arguably unprofitable. Such idioms (eg weigh anchor, take care, break cover, make waves, curry favour, do time, down tools) often resist passivisation (*anchor was weighed) and don't accept pronominalisation (*He broke cover; he broke it before the dogs reached him.) The verby part and the nouny part (I'm avoiding the more precise attributives) are too cohesive in these expressions for one or both. I'd say 'cry foul' is a single lexeme, roughly equal to 'remonstrate'.

Comment: Even so, it isn't just "foul" that is the noun here... it's the phrase, "Foul [play]!" It doesn't resist passivisation if you include the implicit text: "Foul [play] was cried!" Despite the lattermost word being implied, I believe the context and grammar of the word, "foul", remains the same.

Comment: Unlike the other verbonominals I give, the complication here is that "They cried 'Foul [play]!' ", the quotative structure, exists as well as the idiom "They cried foul play." Think of the comparison "He pleaded the Fifth"; there are negligible Google hits for "the Fifth was pleaded/pled". Or again, "She spoke her mind."

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: it's part of a stretched verb ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stretched_verb ) and acts as a noun.

I think most of the answers given have a correct part in it, but none cover the full picture. Language is not a static thing, but it is evolving. There are several attempts in the answers showing where this phrase derived from. But that doesn't mean, that the syntactic role of the word must be the same as where it came from.

The line of thinking presented is:
to cry "there is foul play at hand"
-> to cry "foul play"
-> to cry "foul"
-> to cry foul

The thing is, when people start using a word differently, the role of the word changes.

You can read more about it in Stretched Verb Constructions ( https://books.google.de/books?id=YwiiSmvwv9IC )

P.S.: Yes, English is a highly creative language when it comes to anything, syntax not excluded.

edit: think about other extreme examples like: "to go bananas" - it is not about bananas.
similar concepts to stretched verbs are serial verbs: "come live with me" and phrasal verbs "to look after".

Comment: it means: "too long; didn't read" - indicating that the following sentence is a summary of what I posted in a longer way :)

Comment: We could argue for years about whether it is or not. There is no "right" or "wrong" position on this. All we can do is observe how it is used. For me this is a stretched verb by now and I use it as such. Others may be on another standpoint and use it as in: to cry 'fowl'. Every speaker of the english creates his own version of English and this why languages are alive and changing permanently :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that *foul* in *cry foul* is an ***interjection***.

At least, when the cry of *foul* is actually made, it is interruptive of everything around it - so I believe an *interjection*.

Now that does not mean that the word *foul* cannot be regarded as adjective, noun, and verb, depending on the context. But it is the case with many words that they are capable of use as various parts of speech.

But as a primary-school child I certainly learned of a part of speech called an *interjection*. And if a cry of *foul* isn't one, then I don't know what is.

Comment: The cry of "Foul!" does seem like it would fit an interjection. The idiom "cry foul" doesn't seem like it. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sigh.

Technically it's not "Cry foul", but rather "Cry 'foul'" (though it's usual with such idioms to omit the quotes). The word foul is being quoted, as in "I heard someone cry 'Foul!'." And, of course, "foul" in that sense is short for (depending on your religion) either "Foul ball!", the cry of a baseball umpire, or "Foul play!" from a gambling context.

But regardless of the origin of "foul" in this sense, or its precise meaning, or even the part of speech of the word in normal use, a piece of quoted text functions grammatically as a noun.  This is not affected in any way by the meanings or parts of speech of the words quoted.

"Peter cried 'red vertically fell'" is perfectly valid English syntax, even though the quoted text is nonsense.  *Cried* is a transitive verb and 'red vertically fell' is its object.

Comment: So when the cry of 'foul', meaning 'a foul has been committed' is actually uttered - what is the part of speech then?

Comment: @Mari-LouA & Rathony -- noted.

Comment: @WS2 - One can argue that the "etymology", if you will, of "Foul!" is an elision of the sentence you suggest, or one similar, making "foul" a simple noun.  I don't think it's an interjection since it actually carries specific meaning.

Comment: "Foul [play]" is definitely the object of "cried foul", as is "foul [ball]", and in both instances, regardless of its idiomatic context, "foul" is the adjective describing the nature of the ball or play.

If Peter cried, "Red flag!" the word "red" would still be an adjective. The same would hold true regardless of whether the common vernacular had caused the word "flag" to become implicit and no longer included in the phrase.

Comment: @Crates - There's a difference between "Red flag!" and "Peter cried 'Red flag!'".  In the latter case "Red flag!" is a syntactic atom.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple question.

noun
noun: foul; plural noun: fouls

```
1. (in sports) an unfair or invalid stroke or piece of play, especially one involving interference with an opponent.
```

Yes.  Foul is a noun in this context.  Foul is the thing that is being cried.

Comment: No; it's not. The origins of this phrase suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

"Foul" is a noun, as far as I know, only in a sports context:

*The batter hit a foul* (meaning the ball landed outside of the playing area within the baselines).
Otherwise, it is generally an adjective/modifier.

*That month old cottage cheese is foul.*

*He was asked to leave, because of his use of foul language.*